# Using DataFrame.coalesce to reduce the number of output files

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

When I using Spark HiveContext to do sql like `insert overwrite a select * from b`, at last, there are many small files(400+) on the table's corresponding directory of HDFS, many of them are empty files. So, I try to use `coalesce` to reduce the file numbers, sample codes is:

```
val df = hiveContext.sql("insert overwrite a select * from b")
df.coalesce(50).collect
```

But the output files are still 400+, looks like `coalesce` doesn't work.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: How are you verifying that coalesce doesn't work ? Because as I see you are doiing a collect after this !

Comment: collect is used to trigger the job. Since the job is an insert operation, so there is very little data will be 'collected' to the driver. The data is still written to the HDFS!

Comment: I am not able to understand coalesce is just a shuffle transformation , with every action it will be recalculated ! Can you add more code here the one having the insertion ?

Comment: Thanks @ShivanshSrivastava for the reply. More code? I think the code above is enough to illustrate the problem..What code do you want to know?

Comment: what in your code should result with "the output" ("output files 400+")?

Comment: That is the sql insert overwrite a select * from b join c on somecondition. The data written on table a's HDFS directory.

Comment: what in your code, after the performing the "coalesce(50)" should cause any file to be written?

Comment: See if that works 
val df=sqlcontext.sql("select * from b").coalesce(50).createTempView("temp")
val df2=hiveContext.sql("insert overwrite a select * from temp")
df2.collect

Answer (score 3):

Your example will not merge output files because `coalesce` is done after executing SQL with `insert into` and on this `insert into` results (which I suppose is an empty Dataframe).

Try rewriting code to something like that:

```
hiveContext.sql("select * from b").coalesce(50).write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("a")
```

Comment: Thanks @Marisz. One quick question is how to specify partition for table a.That is, I want to write into one partition of table a.There is a method `partitionedBy` on `DataFrameWriter`,but the method doc doesn't look like  working with Hive Partition.

Comment: `partitionBy` works as expected when writing to Hive, I've just tested it on spark 2.0